# One or more Pycharm project windows can not be reached via application-window switcher in macOS

Tags: pycharm

The `window` menu shows there are a half dozen open projects:

[image]

I can use the `Application Window Switcher` shortcut key (which I have set to `CMD-backtick`) to reach all but one of them:  the `dei.logger` was only reachable by explicitly clicking on it.

I am on `Pycharm Pro 2022.3.1` . This behavior started a few months ago with the previous version of `PyCharm`: it did not happen previously.  It has taken quite some time to understand what is actually going on - since the behavior is that there is NO focus on ANY `Pycharm` window for the culprit project.  So I learnt to switch to a completely different application first (via `CMD-tab`) and then back to `Pycharm` and then select the reluctant  project manually from the list.

I am a keyboardist and use Pycharm for almost everything so it is a continual small annoyance. I'm wondering what changed [/got broken] in the latest two releases to cause this behavior - and if there are any keyboard-friendly workarounds.